# In Asp.net Core 2.0 is IHostingEnvironment extendable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

Currently, Asp.Net core 2 IHostingEnvironment has three boolean properties

- IsProduction
- IsStaging
- IsDevelopment

is it extendable if I wanted to create two additional properties? (e.g. IsTesting, IsCloudDb)

Since I am not a professional programmer I'm not sure how to go about this IF it is doable.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What are you trying to do? Anyway the interface doesn't have those properties, they are extension methods you can create yourself.

Comment: I am trying to extend IHostingEnvironment to create two additional boolean properties, so in Startup, however I set my Environment it will pull the right connection string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are not properties but extension methods for `IHostingEnvironment` interface. All those extension methods do is compare `IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName` with predefined string. You can do the same:

```
public static class EnvironmentExtensions {
    const string CloudDbEnvironment = "CloudDb";
    const string TestingEnvironment = "Testing";

    public static bool IsCloudDb(this IHostingEnvironment env) {
        return env.IsEnvironment(CloudDbEnvironment);
    }

    public static bool IsTesting(this IHostingEnvironment env) {
        return env.IsEnvironment(TestingEnvironment);
    }
}
```

Of course you should set `EnvironmentName` to the related string for those methods to return true.

Comment: Indeed. Best thing about Core is all the source is available! https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/b187c1adc4db343ad985e3d45cfb4f77180966e6/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions/HostingEnvironmentExtensions.cs#L19

Comment: Or the excellent docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.hostingenvironmentextensions?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: @DavidG that's true, though I usually just ctrl-click and Resharper decompiles code for me (or loads from symbols\external sources) :)

Comment: Same here, but not everyone has R#